# GeoCoordinateWatcher only works once in a while

Tags: c#, wpf, location

The following code attempts to get the location of the computer the code is being run on:

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
if (watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000)))
{
    GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;
    if (!coord.IsUnknown)
    {
        Printer.Print(String.Format("Current Lat: {0}, Current Long: {1}", coord.Latitude, coord.Longitude));
    }
    else // Path taken most often
    {
        throw new CommandException("Weather data unknown. (Are location services enabled?)"); 
    }
}
else
{
    throw new CommandException("Weather data unknown. (Are location services enabled?)");
}
```

Every once in a while, the right location is printed, but most of the time, the commented else statement is run. After multiple tests, I realized that whether it not it works is completely random.  Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `coord` when it works? When it doesn't? Are location services enabled? Is the computer on wifi / 3G / something else? Does it have a GPS?

Comment: @mjwills when it works, the value of `coord` is correct with my location. When it doesn't, the value is `{Unknown}`. Location services are enabled; everything I can think of that uses location works. My computer is not a laptop, and it is on wifi. Idk about GPS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the reason you're encountering issues is that you're initializing a new locator, but not waiting for the status to report back that it is ready before checking the location.

```
bool abort = false;
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
if (watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000)))
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    while(watcher.Status != GeoPositionStatus.Ready && !abort)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds > 5)
            abort = true;
    }

    GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;
    if (!coord.IsUnknown)
    {
        Printer.Print(String.Format("Current Lat: {0}, Current Long: {1}", coord.Latitude, coord.Longitude));
    }
    else // Path taken most often
    {
        throw new CommandException("Weather data unknown. (Are location services enabled?)"); 
    }
}
else
{
    throw new CommandException("Weather data unknown. (Are location services enabled?)");
}
```

Basically this adds a check to see if the status is ready and waits up to 5 seconds.

Alternatively, the watcher should typically be set up at a module level and register the `PositionChanged` event so that you only update your print-out when the position actually changes, rather than a polling loop that will reiterate the current position again and again while stationary.